# How can I sort a data.frame (table) based on another object's row.names

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

## I have to write a report where the cross table is ordered based on the frequency of another table. I'm building the first table using the following code:

```
library(descr)

X <- c(rep('Anthony', 6), rep('Marcelo', 4), rep('Luiz', 3), rep('Lind', 2), rep('Cesar', 1), rep('Outros', 6), rep('Ninguém', 6), rep('NS/NR', 6)) 
PESO <- rep(1, length(X))
REG <- sample(c('R1','R2','R3','R4'), length(X), replace=T)
bd <- data.frame(X, PESO, REG)

perc <- (round(freq(bd$X, w=bd$PESO, plot=F), digits=0))
perc <- perc[rownames(perc)!="NA's" & rownames(perc)!='NR' & rownames(perc)!='Total',]
perc <- perc[,-1]
ns <- perc[names(perc)=='NS/NR']
ni <- perc[names(perc)=="Ninguém"]
ou <- perc[names(perc)=="Outros"]
perc <- data.frame('%'=sort(perc[names(perc)!='NS/NR' & names(perc)!="Ninguém" & names(perc)!="Outros"], decreasing=T))
perc <- rbind(perc,ou,ni,ns)
rownames(perc)[rownames(perc)==6 | rownames(perc)==7 | rownames(perc)==8] <- c('Outros', 'Ninguém', 'NS/NR')
perc <- rbind(perc, Total=100, Base=dim(bd)[1])
```

## The outcome is

```
         X.
Anthony  18
Marcelo  12
Luiz      9
Lind      6
Cesar     3
Outros   18
Ninguém  18
NS/NR    18
Total   100
Base     34
```

## Now, when I run the code to cross this variable with another one, I get

```
tab <- round(rbind(prop.table(xtabs(PESO~X+REG, bd),margin=2)*100))
ns <- tab[rownames(tab)=='NS/NR',]
ni <- tab[rownames(tab)=="Ninguém",]
ou <- tab[rownames(tab)=="Outros",]
tab <- tab[rownames(tab)!='NS/NR' & rownames(tab)!="Ninguém" & rownames(tab)!="Outros",]
tab <- tab[order(tab[,1], decreasing=T),]
perc <- rbind(tab,ou,ni,ns,Total=100,Base=apply(xtabs(PESO~X+REG, bd), 2, sum))
rownames(perc)[rownames(perc)=='ou' | rownames(perc)=='ni' | rownames(perc)=='ns'] <- c('Outros', 'Ninguém', 'NS/NR')
perc <- perc[,colnames(perc)!='Total']
```

## The outcome is

```
         R1  R2  R3  R4
Anthony  17  14  25  11
Luiz     17  14   0  11
Marcelo  17   0  17  11
Cesar     0   0   0  11
Lind      0   0  17   0
Outros    0  43  17  11
Ninguém  33  14  17  11
NS/NR    17  14   8  33
Total   100 100 100 100
Base      6   7  12   9
```

## I would like to make this table to have the same order as the first one. Something like:

```
         R1  R2  R3  R4
Anthony  17  14  25  11
Marcelo  17   0  17  11
Luiz     17  14   0  11
Lind      0   0  17   0
Cesar     0   0   0  11 
Outros    0  43  17  11
Ninguém  33  14  17  11
NS/NR    17  14   8  33
Total   100 100 100 100
Base      6   7  12   9
```

## How can I adapt my code to solve this?

## Thanks

Comment: Please add package dependencies and part of this code isn't working. `Error in freq(bd$X, w = bd$PESO, plot = F) :`

Comment: The `xtable` part of this code isn't necessary to reproduce the problem. Please leave it out but include the objects that are necessary.

Comment: Please make your question reproducible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your first block capture the row order

```
perc <- rbind(perc, Total=100, Base=dim(bd)[1])
#add
perc.order <- rownames(perc)
```

Then you can use those row names to sort your final data. So after

```
perc <- perc[,colnames(perc)!='Total']
#add
perc[perc.order, ]
```

You can index an element that has row names using those names as long as they are passed as a character vector. This will only return values that were in the first table. If new values were added, they will not be included in the output.